How to resolve TypeScript errors with ts-jest and ES modules in Jest?
I'm encountering some issues with TypeScript and Jest, and I could really use some guidance. I'm trying to use ts-jest with ES modules, but I'm running into several compiler and test errors.
When I run npx tsc, I get the following error:
api/handlers/facts/facts-handler.test.ts:12:48 - error TS2345: Argument of type '{ has_readme: boolean; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
12         $queryRaw: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([
13           { has_readme: true },
   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
14         ])

Here's the relevant test code:
describe("attribute-api", () => {
  describe("readme attribute", () => {
    it("returns true when readme exists", async () => {
      const mockDbClient = {
        $queryRaw: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([
          { has_readme: true },
        ])
      };
      const readme = await getAttributes(mockDbClient as PrismaClient, "sp-test", SupportedAttributes.ReadMe);
      expect(readme).toEqual({ has_readme: true });
    });
  });
});

The error occurs when I try to use import { jest } from '@jest/globals'. If I don't import jest, then the npx tsc command works fine, but I get the following error during test execution:
 FAIL  api/handlers/facts/facts-handler.test.ts
  ● attribute-api › readme attribute › returns true when readme exists

    ReferenceError: jest is not defined

       8 |     it("returns true when readme exists", async () => {
       9 |       const mockDbClient = {
> 10 |         $queryRaw: jest.fn().mockResolvedValue([
         |                    ^
      11 |           { has_readme: true },
      12 |         ])
      13 |       };

I've tried modifying my jest.config.ts
import type { JestConfigWithTsJest } from 'ts-jest'

const jestConfig: JestConfigWithTsJest = {
  preset: 'ts-jest/presets/default-esm', // or other ESM presets
  extensionsToTreatAsEsm: ['.ts'],
  testEnvironment: "node",
  testPathIgnorePatterns: ["<rootDir>/dist"],
  moduleNameMapper: {
    '^(\\.{1,2}/.*)\\.js$': '$1',
  },
  transform: {
    // '^.+\\.[tj]sx?$' to process ts,js,tsx,jsx with `ts-jest`
    // '^.+\\.m?[tj]sx?$' to process ts,js,tsx,jsx,mts,mjs,mtsx,mjsx with `ts-jest`
    '^.+\\.tsx?$': [
      'ts-jest',
      {
        useESM: true,
      },
    ],
  },
}

export default jestConfig


You have to tell jest the type of $queryRaw in order to add the has_readme property in the mock, otherwise there is a type error that the resolved value (never) does not include the property. mockedFunction can take a generic argument, and you can either apply that inline:


const queryRawMock=$queryRaw as jest.MockedFunction<typeof $queryRaw>;

$queryRaw: queryRawMock.mockResolvedValue([
          { has_readme: true },
        ])



or in a type definition:


type QueryRaw={
has_readme:boolean;
}

const queryRawMock=$queryRaw as jest.MockedFunction<QueryRaw[]>;

$queryRaw: queryRawMock([
          { has_readme: true },
        ])



If you do use queryRawMock in multiple tests, make sure to properly clean up the mock between tests.

thanks jamesTobey... Actually, I tried this but then I received another error


Apologies, Semural- mockedFunction takes the generic, not mockResolvedValue. I updated my answer to provide the correct intermediate step of typing jest.mockedFunction.

How does queryRaw should look like?

It's unclear from your code snippet exactly what properties queryRaw has, although we can infer that has_readme is a boolean property. Using the typeof operator tells the compiler to implicitly set the type of the mock, using the function definition of queryRaw. Alternatively, you can build on the explicit type definition of QueryRaw in the second code snippet.

$queryRaw is a database query method in Prisma, and I could not find any proper documentation how to mock this.
I tried const $queryRaw = jest.fn(); but did not help.

I didn't realize that your original question pertained to mocking the Prisma Client.  It looks like you will have to replace mockDbClient with one of the two approaches suggested in this article: https://www.prisma.io/docs/orm/prisma-client/testing/unit-testing#example-unit-tests
